# Infer type from return value

Tags: typescript

It seems that Typescript is not able to infer that a variable is not `null` or `undefined` if the check for the existence of that variable was done in another function. Here is an example.

(I'm using Typescript with --strictNullChecks turned on.)

```
const login = (email: string) => {
    console.log(email);
}

const handleButtonClick = (email?: string) => {
    const error = validate(email);
    if (error) {
        return;
    }

    return login(email);
}

const validate = (email?: string) => {
    if (!email) {
        return 'There was an error'
    }
}
```

Typescript complains in `handleButtonClick` that you can not call `login` with an email that may be undefined. However, we are making sure that `email` is defined in the `validate` call.

Is it possible for Typescript to figure this out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct, TypeScript does not keep track of narrowing done outside the current function. This is one of the examples of when you might use a non-null assertion:

```
const handleButtonClick = (email?: string) => {
    const error = validate(email);
    if (error) {
        return;
    }

    return login(email!);
}
```

I hate non-null assertions. One way I sometimes avoid this is to turn my validator functions into a [type-guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards), which technically just return true or false but also enable type narrowing at the call-site:

```
const login = (email: string) => {
    console.log(email);
}

const handleButtonClick = (email?: string) => {
    if (isValidEmail(email)) {
        return login(email);
    }
    console.log("Invalid email!");
}

const isValidEmail = (email?: string): email is string => {
    return !!email;
}
```

[Example in playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20login%20%3D%20(email%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(email)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20handleButtonClick%20%3D%20(email%3F%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(isValidEmail(email))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20login(email)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20isValidEmail%20%3D%20(email%3F%3A%20string)%3A%20email%20is%20string%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20!!email%3B%0A%7D) (check `strictNullChecks` in options)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wanted to use type-guards but I'm actually validating several inputs in the validate function. I don't think there is a way to define a type-guard for multiple variables, is there?

Comment: Well, you could achieve that by using an object. For example `hasAllValidInput({ email, name, age })` which is type guard of something like `hasAllValidInput(inputs: { email?: string; name?: string; age?: number }): inputs is { email: string; name: string; age: number; }`. You could also just write `null` checks, though redundant after your validator.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. Thanks for the tip.